# Rails 4 - Production enviroment just writing one line in production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, production

I want to get the errors in production.log, but i have only one line that is:

```
# Logfile created on 2016-09-06 11:44:55 -0500 by logger.rb/47272
```

My configuration en production.rb about logs is:

```
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.log_level = :debug
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger), you want something like this:

```
Rails.logger     = Logger.new 'log/production.log'
config.log_level = :debug
```

You can also set `Rails.logger.level` from the console, but I recommend setting your log file and log level in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) such as [config/application.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-application-rb) unless you're actively trying to debug a running instance in production. Debugging in production is not a DevOps best-practice, so I'd avoid that if at all possible.